# how to make ng-click must be triggered only when device-width<480px?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where I need ng-click to work for devices with a width less than 480px but not for anything greater. I have tried an if condition but it is not working.The toggle function must be work only in smaller device and the list must not be affected in desktop view,if toggled in smaller device.

I have tried the following;

Here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8EDvThGbKc0vAQhqfqzT?p=preview)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.width = $window.document.body.clientWidth;

  if ($scope.width < 480) {
    $scope.showList = false;
  } else {
    $scope.showList = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 widget" ng-click="showList = !showList;">
          <h2>sign in data</h2>
          <article class="widget_content">
            <ul ng-show="showList">
              <li>Get a quote</li>
              <li>Send quote</li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 widget">
          <h2>CONTACT US</h2>
          <article class="widget_content">
            <ul>
              <li>Find a branch</li>
              <li>Contact us</li>

            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 widget">
          <h2>ABOUT</h2>
          <article class="widget_content">
            <ul>
              <li>Careers</li>
              <li>data</li>

            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get device width with following

```
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
```

You can check an if condition in the click handler.

```
if(width<480) {
   handleClick();
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.width = ($window.innerWidth > 0) ? $window.innerWidth : $window.document.body.clientWidth;
  if ($scope.width < 480) {
    $scope.showList = false;
  } else {
    $scope.showList = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 widget" ng-click="showList = !showList;">
          <h2>sign in data</h2>
          <article class="widget_content">
            <ul ng-show="showList">
              <li>Get a quote</li>
              <li>Send quote</li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 widget">
          <h2>CONTACT US</h2>
          <article class="widget_content">
            <ul>
              <li>Find a branch</li>
              <li>Contact us</li>

            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 widget">
          <h2>ABOUT</h2>
          <article class="widget_content">
            <ul>
              <li>Careers</li>
              <li>data</li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you want you can create a directive

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$window', function ($window) {

     return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'           
     };

     function link(scope, element, attrs){
       angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){
           scope.width= $window.innerWidth;
       });    
     }    
 }]);
```

And use it on your div:

```
<div my-directive ng-if="width > 320">
```

Comment: how would you set up a watcher on width to check its value dynamically?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I think we need not set a watcher since that can be achieved to window resize event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like :

you can check width through JS (id):

```
document.getElementById(id).clientWidth;
```

Also, you can check width through angular.element

```
angular.element(document.getElementById(id)).clientWidth;
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".class")[0]).clientWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

put the function defined in the snippet to all lists which you want to toggle...

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$window) {

$scope.toggleInSmallDevices = function(){
    var screenWidthNow = $window.document.body.clientWidth;
    console.log(screenWidthNow);
    if (screenWidthNow<480){
        $scope.showList = !$scope.showList; 
    }
    else {
        $scope.showList = true;
    }

}

        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <body ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="showList=true; toggleInSmallDevices();">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 widget" ng-click="toggleInSmallDevices()">
             <h2>sign in data</h2>
                <article class="widget_content">
                    <ul ng-show="showList">
                        <li>Get a quote</li>
                        <li>Send quote</li>
                    </ul>
                 </article>
      </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 widget">
             <h2>CONTACT US</h2>
                <article class="widget_content">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Find a branch</li>
                        <li>Contact us</li>
                       
                 </ul>
                 </article>
      </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 widget">
                <h2>ABOUT</h2>
                <article class="widget_content">
                  <ul>
                         <li>Careers</li>
                        <li>data</li>
                       
                 </ul>
                </article>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In below link the solution of Responsive web design it is pretty much explained similar to your problem.

Used media queries for checking width less than 480px and based on that toggle element class to show/ hide menus on element click function in JavaScript

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDh7Mdl2oww&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9g9Vh9MAA-XKnfJsWZnPZFw&index=9

Thanks